# Wordpress - Getting the image from a category

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Im using the taxonomy images plugin which allows me to assign images to categories ... im not quite sure how to show it on the front end though.

My code that displays categories is as follows:

```
$cat = get_query_var('cat');
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'id',
    'child_of' => $cat,
    'hide_empty' => 0
);
$categories = get_categories($args);
foreach($categories as $category) {
    echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" class="cat-c-top-bg">' . "\n";
    echo '  <h4>' . $category->name . '</h4>' . "\n";
    echo '      <div class="icon-view">' . "\n";
    echo '      </div>' . "\n";
    echo '      <div>' . "\n";
    echo '          <img src="" width="164" height="164"></img>' . "\n";
    echo '      </div>' . "\n";
    echo '  <div class="cat-bot-ext_bg">' . "\n";
    echo '  </div>' . "\n";
    echo '</a>' . "\n";
}
```

Which works PERFECT ... although, whe i enter the code supplied by the image plugin, it displays the image as many times as there are categories, this is the code im putting inside teh foreach statement above

```
$terms = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-get-terms', '' );
if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
    print '<ul>';
    foreach( (array) $terms as $term ) {
        print '<li><a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term, $term->taxonomy ) ) . '">' . wp_get_attachment_image( $term->image_id, 'detail' ) . '</li>';
    }
    print '</ul>';
}
```

Any help on this would be great.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

the statement

```
$terms = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-get-terms', '' )
```

is a replacement for get_terms or get_categories. So you should do something like this

```
$terms = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-get-terms', '')
foreach( (array) $terms as $term ) {
  print wp_get_attachment_image( $term->image_id, 'thumbnail' );
  echo '  <h4>' . $term->name . '</h4>' . "\n";
  //everything you wanna print
}
```